# FFMPEG not able to listen for rtmp and turn it into HLS

Tags: ffmpeg

Based on my understanding, this command should work...

> ffmpeg -listen 1 -i
>   rtmp://my-host-name.com:8000/thing/input.ts 
>   -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -ac 1 -strict -2 -crf 30 -profile:v baseline -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -start_number 1 stream.m3u8

It is listening for an rtmp connection on port 8000. After an rtmp stream connects it should start generating an HLS stream on the fly in the current directory.

Somewhere else I am sending the stream like so:

> ffmpeg -i input.ts -f mpegts
>   rtmp://my-host-name.com:8000/thing/input.ts

On the sending side things seem to be normal, but on the listening side nothing seems to be happening, except it is throwing lots or errors like this:

> [rtmp @ 0x9a1280] Unknown packet type received 0x78
>
> [rtmp @ 0x9a1280] Unknown packet type received 0x00
>
> [rtmp @ 0x9a1280] Unknown packet type received 0x71
>
> [rtmp @ 0x9a1280] Unknown packet type received 0x00

I don't know if those are just superfluous or not. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried adding `-f mpegts` bevor the `-i rtmp://...` ?

Comment: Awesome, this was indeed the problem. For some reason I was still having some issues but after changing both formats to flv and reencoding at the source things are working beautifully. Thanks.

Comment: RTMP is Adobe's protocol for streaming FLV but you set a different output format. Normally, just `-i rtmp://` should work.

Answer (score 1):

As Eugen Rieck indicated, I needed to indicate on the listening side what the format was that was being received.